# Is there a pre-defined ThisIsABugException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

The .NET Framework has a lot of pre-defined exceptions. For example, if an invalid parameter was passed to my method, I'm supposed to raise an `ArgumentException` (or `ArgumentNullException`, if the paramter was `null`). If a method is called that is invalid for the current object state, I'm supposed to raise an `InvalidOperationException`.

Is there some pre-defined exception for the "*this code should never be reached*" case? Here's an example:

```
void myMethod() {
    int a;

    ... /* Some complex code that manipulates a. In the end, "a" can only be 1 or 2. */

    switch (a) {
        case 1: ...
        case 2: ...
        default:  // just an extra sanity check
            // Oops, we should never be here.
            // There's apparently some bug in the code above.
            throw new ThereIsABugInTheCodeException();
    }
}
```

I don't think creating my own exception for such a rare case is justified. On the other hand, just throwing `Exception` [is discouraged as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx). I guess some kind of `AssertionFailedException` would be appropriate, but I did not find any in the .net Framework. (Note that [Trace.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.assert.aspx) does not throw an exception, so that's not an option either.)

---

**EDIT**: To clarify: `a` is NOT an argument. Let me rephrase the question to make it clearer: In the middle of a method I do a sanity check (just to make sure, it should not be necessary if the code in the beginning of the method is correct). I find out the sanity check fails and would like to throw an exception. Which one do I throw? I don't think that `ArgumentException` is the correct answer, since [`ArgumentException` should only be thrown if the *caller* of the method did something wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/01/22/faq-what-exception-should-i-throw-instead-of-the-reserved-exceptions-found-by-donotraisereservedexceptiontypes.aspx). That is not the case here. The *method itself* realizes at runtime that it contains a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly enough the .NET Framework does not contain an exception to describe logical or internal errors. But on the other hand the .NET Framework should have a quality level where there shouldn't be a need to throw exceptions for internal errors. Would you trust a .NET API call that in the documentation stated that it might throw an `InternalErrorException`? Remember that exceptions derived from `SystemException` are exceptions used by the framework. It can be useful to reuse these exceptions but the exceptions were created for use by the framework and not your framework/application.

You can use `ArgumentException`, `ArgumentNullException`, `ArgumentOufOfRangeException`, `NotSupportedException` and `InvalidOperationException` in cases where your methods a called in an unexpected way.

You can also create your own `InternalErrorException`.

Microsofts more general solution to this problem is [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx). Many contracts can be checked at compile time helping you produce better code and you can use `Contract.Assume` and `Contract.Assert` to verify conditions in your code. The rewriter will insert code that will throw a `ContractException` if the condition is false. This exception has been crafted in a special way (from the [DevLabs Code Contracts documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf)):

> The ContractException type is not a public type and is emitted as a nested private type into each assembly for which runtime contract checking is enabled. It is thus not possible to write catch handlers catching only ContractException. Contract exceptions can thus only be handled as part of a general exception backstop. The rationale for this design is that programs should not contain control logic that depends on contract failures, just like programs should not catch ArgumentNullException or similar validation exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

For the case you show I would also go with an `ArgumentException`, possibly an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

**Edit** I didn't look closely enough and though the `switch` was on method argument, but apparently it isn't. So an `ArgumentException` is probably, not applicable. The rest of my answer stands as it is.

However, there really might be cases when program state is totally unexpected. For such cases I wouldn't even use an exception (that can be caught). In such cases one could argue, that security and data integrity is at stake, so the only sensible thing is to exit the application as fast as possible (to minimize the chance of corrupting state further).

You should probably think about using [`Debug.Assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx) or [`Trace.Assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk4kachs.aspx) in that case, or roll your own handler that essentially calls [`Environment.FailFast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx).

Whether such behavior is correct or acceptable for your application is a decision you have to make.

**Update**: You might also want to look into [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/faq.aspx). Which AFAIK, can be tailored in their runtime behavior to either throw exceptions, abort the process or do nothing.

Comment: Both Debug.Assert and Trace.Assert just show a message box and then continue executing the code.

Comment: Yes, they do (by default). You can [change](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2340890/21567) that behavior. Personally, I would go with something like Assert in development and FailFast in production code.

Comment: FailFast is too harsh in this case. I want this to bubble up to the UI layer, hence I was looking for a suitable exception.

Comment: Fair enough. Note that I assume(d) that their are circumstances, where this is not, or no longer, safe to do. Both security and data integrity wise. But then I mostly come from a server point of view. So YMMV :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ArgumentException` in this case.

You are getting an unexpected value for your `a` argument.

```
throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unexpected value {0} for a.", a);
```

Though depending on the exact scenario, [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) may be more suitable, as @todda.speot.is commented.

Comment: I think you want [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx).

Comment: But `a` is not an Argument of my method. It's a local variable! I've updated the example in my question to emphasize that.

Comment: @Heinzi - It is still a bad value being passed in to the `switch` argument.

Comment: True, but the caller of my method is not responsible for that. To quote from [some Microsoft recommendations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/01/22/faq-what-exception-should-i-throw-instead-of-the-reserved-exceptions-found-by-donotraisereservedexceptiontypes.aspx): *Exceptions that derive from ArgumentException [...] and NotSupportedException should only be thrown in situations that are avoidable (such as passing a null argument) and if thrown, would indicate a bug in the calling code.*

Comment: @todda.speot.is: `ArgumentException` seems more appropriate to me in this scenario, since the `case` values in the `switch` statement don't necessarily form any range. For instance, one can expect to get either 1 or 5 but instead gets 3. It *is* within a range [1, 5] but still not valid.

Comment: @Heinzi - Fine, but where does the value for `a` come from?

Comment: @Oded: Some code that's supposed to return 1 or 2. I'm just doing a sanity check by providing the `default:` branch at all.

Comment: @Heinzi - The recommendation looks like it fits your situation... This is a judgement call. I think that `ArgumentException` covers this situation (the argument to the `switch` block), you don't.

Comment: @Oded -1 Strongly disagree.  `a` is not an argument to the switch block; switch blocks do not accept arguments.  The expression used to determine the target `case` is referred to as the *switch expression*.  Throwing an `ArgumentException` in this case would be extremely harmful since it conveys incorrect information to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining and throwing a custom exception types which would, by their nature, identify the application layer in which the problematic condition occurred.  I would also suggest catching many types of exceptions which would indicate logic or state-related problems and rethrowing as custom types.  Otherwise if someone calls your method and has an `ArgumentException` thrown at him, the caller will have no idea whether that is a consequence of his passing invalid arguments to your code, or whether it indicates some internal problem with your code.  Note that because of things like function inlining, a StackTrace may not list all the methods involved in a call chain.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the "bug exception" concept exists?

In your example, it's definitely a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception if `a` is an argument.

If your code tries to execute some code that **isn't ever supposed to be executed**, then I think something more relevant than "*Hey! Bug here!*" needs to be thrown **upstream**.

Comment: That's exactly it: The code *isn't ever supposed to be executed*. What do I throw in this case?

Answer (score 0):

ThisIsABugException is conceptually incorrect, I would say.

If your method's contract is passed (parameters are correct so there are no ArgumentExceptions) your method technically should not fail. Why should it if all the parameters are correct and the logic of the method itself is correct?

So when you check your method contract (parameters) you raise ArgumentException or its children.

If within your method you call something unreliable and receive some weird result, then you probably whould raise something meaningful rather than failing with "oh, bug! bug!". Bug indeed, so what? I'd rather raise something meaningful in context of operation.

If you have to throw because of your business rules, say you were asked to deactivate an account, and parameters are correct, but during the method you have discovered that this account is already inactive, this is, indeed, an invalid operation, then InvalidOperationException will do, that's why we have this "generic" exception in .NET.

That's why you never want to raise ThisIsABugException or something similar.

Comment: `Why should it if all the parameters are correct and the logic of the method itself is correct?` -- that's exactly the point: At runtime, the method detects (by means of a sanity check) that it is *not* correct, i.e., it contains a bug that only the developer can fix.